# How to wait asynchronus method on android

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I have this class to connect with twitter

```
public class TwitterConnect {
    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient;
    StatusesService statusesService;
    Long [] ids;

    public TwitterConnect(){
        twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
        statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
        callHomeTimeLine();
    }

    private void callHomeTimeLine(){

        statusesService.homeTimeline(200, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
                Long [] ids = new Long[result.data.size()];
                int i=0;

                for (Tweet tweet:result.data) {
                    //tweet.id;
                    Log.w("Twwet",tweet.id+" ");
                    ids[i] = result.data.get(i).id;
                    i++;
                }
                setIds(ids);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.e("FAILURE", "Fallo en callHomeTimeLine");
            }
        });

    }

   private void setIds(Long [] ids){
     this.ids = ids;
   }

    public Long[] getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
}
```

And I use this clas on an activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_following);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        TwitterConnect twc = new TwitterConnect();
        this.ids = twc.getIds()//ids its always null
;
```

But the this.ids is always null,on succces method its asynchronous ,how I can wait for it? In edbug mode ,the data is correctly retrieved but the activity uses the ids array before the asynchronous method finished.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to "wait" for an asynchronous task to finish is (in your case), like this:

In your TwitterConnect Class, add an interface:

```
interface Idsinterface {
    void setIds(Long[] ids);
}
```

and pass it as parameter to TwitterConnect Constructor, that it looks like this:

```
public class TwitterConnect {
    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient;
    StatusesService statusesService;
    Long [] ids;

    public TwitterConnect(IdsInterface idsInterface){
        twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
        statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
        callHomeTimeLine(idsInterface);
    }

    private void callHomeTimeLine(IdsInterface idsInterface){

        statusesService.homeTimeline(200, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
                Long [] ids = new Long[result.data.size()];
                int i=0;

                for (Tweet tweet:result.data) {
                    //tweet.id;
                    Log.w("Twwet",tweet.id+" ");
                    ids[i] = result.data.get(i).id;
                    i++;
                }
                idsInterface.setIds(ids);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.e("FAILURE", "Fallo en callHomeTimeLine");
            }
        });

    }

    private void setIds(Long [] ids){
        this.ids = ids;
    }

    public Long[] getIds() {
        return ids;
    }

    interface IdsInterface {
        void setIds(Long[] ids);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this Class like this:

```
new TwitterConnect(TwitterConnect.IdsInterface() {
       @Override
       void setIds(Long[] ids) {
           YourActivity.this.ids = ids;
           //rest of your code here
    });
```